# Setting the tcsh classpath fpr weka.jar

Tags: classpath, weka, tcsh

I have a Java program that imports some of the weka packages. Running the program using Eclipse was really simple, and all I had to do was to use the "Configure build path" to add weka.jar.

I am trying to run the same program using the `tcsh` shell. `javac programname.java` throws an error as the classpath doesn't have `weka.jar` appended to it. Could somebody please tell me how I could append `weka.jar` without modifying the existing classpath?

I tried

```
setenv CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/files/weka-3-7-9/weka.jar
```

However, that throws error

> `"bad modifier"`

Answer (score 1):

To add something to the classpath for only one command use the -classpath parameter.

So something like:

```
javac -classpath $CLASSPATH:/home/files/weka-3-7-9/weka.jar *
```

should work if you want to compile all the sources in the current folder. I use bash, but I think the parameter is not shell specific.